# How to create dynamic tableview with multiple row in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, tableview

I want to create dynamically table view with multiple rows which contains different data. I don't know how to create new row in swift. I want to create 3 rows and add different data to each row. I Know i can update array data and reload tableview.But when i updated data  in loop and reloaded tableview then only last data is displaying. Tableview missing data which is added in for loop at index 2. 
This is my code :

var i = 0

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y:200 ,width: self.view.frame.width, height: 400)
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.layer.borderWidth = 2

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return products.count
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


    let tf = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 320, y: 10*i , width: 300, height:20))
    tf.placeholder = "_"
    tf.tag = indexPath.row
    tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)

    let pest = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10*i, width: 300, height: 60))

     pest.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
     pest.numberOfLines = 0
     pest.text = self.products[indexPath.row]

    let pp = UILabel()
    pp.text = "PP"


    cell.contentView.addSubview(pest)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(tf)



   return cell

}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    createTable()
}

  func createTable(){
    for index in 1...3{
        if(index == 2){
             i = index
             self.products = ["r1","r2","r3","r4"]
             tableView.reloadData()


        }
      else  if(index == 3){

            i = index
            self.products = ["d1","d2","d3","d4"]
            tableView.reloadData()

        }
        else{

        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you update your data in `products`, you can call `tableView.reloadData()` which will call all your tableView functions again. Assuming you've set those up so they reflect what you want, this should create a new row.

Comment: I want to update data in products twice. But if i updated my data twice and called tableView.reloadData() only last data is displaying. First data is not appearing in table.

Comment: Are you saying that the updating data in `products` is not appearing in your tableView after calling `reloadData()`?

Comment: self.products = ["d1","d2","d3","d4"] is appearing in tableview . But   self.products = ["r1","r2","r3","r4"] is not appearing in tableview.